# Game Center displayName error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

```
error: property 'displayName' not found on object of type 'GKPlayer *'
```

is what I'm getting in Xcode. This makes no sense because it's documented and shows up in the code completion. This is the only property on GKPlayer that is giving me an issue.

I tried changing displayName to a message [player displayName]. This compiles with a warning and crashes on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Found the iOS specific documentation. The displayName property is only available on iOS6+ (bummer). Still not sure why this gives a compile time error though..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/GKPlayer/displayName